# Transferring Lists between winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Normally I use something like

```
public List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
public Total(List<Item> i)
{
    itemList = i;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

but now I'm getting

> Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is less
>   accessible than method
>   'Budgeting_Program.Total.Total(System.Collections.Generic.List)'  C:\Users\Mika\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\Budgeting Program\Budgeting
>   Program\Total.cs  22  16  Budgeting Program

I'm not quite sure what this means.

Comment: Make the `Item` class public

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `Item` class public as well.

even you set `itemList` as public if `Item` class not `public` you can't access it from other class

[**Compiler Error CS0052**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/997yz02a.aspx)

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'type' is less accessible than
>   field 'field' The type of a field cannot be less accessible than the
>   field itself because all public constructs must return a publicly
>   accessible object.